# Unclear theorem about vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, independence

Can anyone explain the following theorem? When I try to understand it, it seems like a contradiction of a basis.

[image]

Is the vector `v` mentioned in the theorem not a linear combination of all the vectors in S, given the way `v` is derived? If it is a linear combination it can't be a basis, right? There is some part I don't understand correctly, I suppose.

Comment: The theorem states that you can replace any vector of your basis by a non-nul linear combination of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this theorem is saying, essentially, is that, given one basis of a finite-dimensional space, you can swap out one of the basis vectors for another, provided the new vector is a linear combination of the old set: the new set will still be a basis. You'll notice this is a Lemma, not a Theorem: I expect the authors are moving towards some theorems involving change-of-basis, which is quite important in linear algebra. This particular Lemma is not that important by itself except as a stepping-stone to change-of-basis.

Remember what a basis is: a set of linearly independent vectors such that any arbitrary vector is a linear combination of vectors in the set.

Comment: Thank you, I would understand it if the theorem said v was a lin. comb. of V, not a lin. comb. of the basis. But if v is a lin. comb of the basis, the basis is not lin. indep. anymore, no?

Comment: It doesn't mean the basis is no longer linearly independent. It does mean the set $\{v,S\}$ is not linearly independent. But now, because you're subtracting one vector from $S$ and substituting $v$, you still have the same number of total vectors, so that $(S\setminus\{w_i\})\cup \{v\}$ is still linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. I didn't think that the linear combination of v was intended to be the sum of the original basis. Now it makes sense.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The key part of the lemma is that the $i$th component of $v$ must be nonzero. This ensures that $v$ is outside the span of the  other $w$s. Since the $w$s form a basis, it follows that $v$ is linearly independent from the other $w$s, and therefore replacing $w_i$ by $v$ yields a basis. The $i$ in the equation $\gamma_i \neq 0$ is the specific $i$ mentioned earlier in the lemma.